# Are animal whiskers a useful monitoring tool?

Tags: ecology, mammals

I have come across studies that have used stable isotope values from seal/sea lion whiskers to infer foraging ecology. However, I am also aware that whiskers can fall off and then grow back. Is there a way to determine the age of a specific whisker, to verify the timeline stable isotope samples represent? E.g. if a sample is taken every *x* mm that correlates to the foraging ecology *y* years ago.

Comment: theforestecologist might have a great answer for this. For me, one wait is to feed harmless radioisotope carbons during a specific observation time. If you can regress one way to another the rate of whisker growth, then I would be probably feasible

Comment: Whiskers have very similar science to other hair follicles. You need to specifiy the types of whiskers, rat, seal or tiger whiskers?

Answer (score 1):

I expect that vibrissae growth rate would depend on the species, the type of vibrissae, time of year, etc. One paper that comes to mind is Zhao & Schell 2004, which estimated growth patterns of harbor seals (*Phoca vitulina*) using labeled tracers:
https://www.int-res.com/abstracts/meps/v281/p267-273/. I am sure there are other papers that have studied pinniped vibrissae growth rates. I recommend a more specific search using Google Scholar.